# Diferença entre datas em Meses, para intervalo >= 12

Tags: php, data

Para se descobrir a diferença entre duas datas, deve-se usar o [date_diff()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.diff.php).

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2016-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2018-10-11');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

return $interval->m; // months
```

O código funciona perfeitamente enquanto a diferença entre as datas for menor que 12. Se for maior ou igual, `$interval->m` retorna `0`, porém eu preciso que ele retorne o número de meses em qualquer caso.

Alguem conhece algum workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não precisa de *workaround*, basta adicionar 12 meses pra cada ano.

```
return $interval->m + $interval->y * 12;
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/rRx2Kp)**.